# The correct grammar of "verb" + "conjunction" + "verb"

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjunctions

I have seen the usage of both versions:

> I am doing this **to get** more attention **and** **to seek** for opportunities.
>
> I am doing this **to get** more attention **and** **seek** for opportunities.

Which one is correct? Or is it merely different styles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both options are fine. If the second part is an afterthought, you would probably repeat *to* (and possibly add a comma before the conjunction). Otherwise, most people probably prefer the shorter version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both okay.  You can conjoin any two phrases of the same type to get another phrase of that same type.  The structure is

> I am doing this [[to [get more attention]] and [to [seek for opportunities]]].

where "and" connects two to-infinitives and gives you a to-infinitive that goes with "doing this".  But the two lower verb phrases could also be connected:

> I am doing this [to [[get more attention] and [seek for opportunities]]].

giving a verb phrase in construction with the "to".

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

*I am doing this to get more attention **and seek opportunities**.*

> An American's Guide To Doing Business In China: ... - Page 113
>
> Mike Saxon - 2006 - Many rural people, especially the young, go to a
>   city **to make money and seek opportunities** for advancement.

Also consider at Google Books (not vanilla Google):

"and seek opportunities to"
About 11,800 results

["and seek for opportunities to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%20and%20to%20seek%20for%20opportunities.%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22and%20seek%20for%20opportunities%20to%22)
About 61 results

Enough said.

> _
>   Now, at the **British National Corpus**:

[seek opportunities](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=seek+opportunities&mysubmit=Go)
6 solutions

seek for opportunities
0

[look for opportunities](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=look%20for%20opportunities&mysubmit=Go)
7 solutions

Comment: Though irrelevant to the question, should it be **seek** or **seek for**? Thanks!

Comment: Neither option seems quite idiomatic in British English. To "seek attention" is a common phrase, and you can describe somebody as "attention-seeking" or "an attention-seeker". But "*getting* more attention and *seeking* [for] something else" sounds a bit strange. I think search for opportunities" or "look for opportunities" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @ alephzero Updated stats at the BNC. Mind want to have a look. Pretty much the  same numbers. However "[for] something else" is a good point.

Comment: @alephzero Thanks for adding to the answer! Do your statement only hold for British English? I have been learning/using American English. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: No, only the references to BNC at the end are British.

Comment: @Thomas Hsieh I'm British, so I can't give you a definitive answer about American English.

Comment: @alephzero That's ok, I appreciate your help regardless.